# Signalr inactivity timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr

I have googled many things related to this issue. I am doing *signalr* connection using WebSocket and longpooling, I am pinging the server every 30 sec  from the connection.
When I load the first time, I don't doing anything on the page, no refresh, after some time connection is disconnected due to inactivity(he client has been inactive since 26/03/2018 30000ms and it has exceeded the inactivity timeout), and reconnected again as I have written reconnect function,
though if I calling ping method to server every 20 sec after some time server is disconnected and I don't know why.

I have enabled `logging=true` on client side,
my client is HTML page.

If the server is not reconnected, an error like

> longpooling request is failed

occurs. On the server `keepalive` is `null`.

The first time the client is able to reconnect, but the second time not. 
I don't know why the server disconnects, as I am using longpooling. 
The `ping` method is an empty method only for the heartbeat I used.

The application is hosted using Amazon ELB.
Please help, I have tried for 3-4 days, but I could not find the issue.

Comment: Why did you remove all the formatting from your question?  I have rolled back your edit, please make edits to **increase** readability, not reduce.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue or was it a bug?